# Using {{store}} directive to get url for different store view

Tags: magento2, multistore, cms

Scenario:
In a static block, I need to generate the url for a specific page but not in the current store view, but to a specific store view / website.

Question:
Is there a combination of parameters that can be passed to the `{{store}}` directive to make this happen?
Something like `{{store _direct="page-here" store_code=some-code}}`  or instead of store code, store_id or anything else.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apparently it does not work with `_direct` attribute and a different store view, but  it works like this:

```
{{store url="page-url-here" _scope_to_url=1 _scope=store-code-or-id-here _nosid=1}}
```

`_nosid=1` is optional. If you remove it the url will look like `http://example/com/page-url-here/?SID=ajshajkshdaj`

Leaving it in place removes the `SID` parameter